# Python, Use attributes of class A instances in class B

Tags: python, class, attributes

I am trying to get the hang of OOP in Python and currently writing a simple 2D finite element analysis program.

To begin with, I have created two classes called `Nodes` and `Elements` with the attributes shown in the code. The `Elements` class contains an attribute called length which has to be calculated based on the x and y coordinates of the start- and end nodes. These coordinates are contained within two instances of the `Nodes` class that are input by the user.

My first question is how can I pass these into the `Elements` class to be used by the `calc_length` method that computes the length of an element (a rod or a beam).

The second question which I cannot find an answer to is whether or not I need to declare the `self_length` attribute in the `__init__()` of the `Elements` class if it is calculated in the respective method?

```
import math as mt
import numpy as np


class Nodes:
    
    def __init__(self,number,x_glob,y_glob):
        self.number = number
        self.xGlobal = x_glob
        self.yGlobal = y_glob
      

class Elements:
    def __init__(self,number,length,start_node,end_node):
        self.number = number
        self.length = length #delare this attribute if it is created using the calc_length method?
        self.start_node = start_node
        self.end_node = end_node

      
    def calc_length(self):
        self.length = mt.sqrt((x_global_start-x_global_end)**2 + (y_global_start-y_global_end)**2 ) 

#I need to somehow pass the x_global_start,x_global_end,
#y_global_start,y_global_end to this method from two separate 
#instances of the Nodes class
```

Furthermore, this is the code that I use to create instance arrays of n-number of nodes.

```
num_of_nodes = int(input('Enter the number of nodes: '))

#create an empty array for the "Nodes" class attributes
arr_nodes = np.zeros(shape=(num_of_nodes,3))


for i in range(num_of_nodes):
    print('Node', i,':')
    
    #User input of the global nodal coordinates
    x_global_in = input( 'Global x coordinate [m] ' )      
    y_global_in = input( 'Global y coordinate [m] ' ) 
    
    #Instantiation of the "Nodes" class
    arr_nodes[i] = Nodes(i, x_global_in, y_global_in)
```

I would welcome any suggestions. I am just learning to program, so please don't judge too harshly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`calc_length` should use `self.start_node` and `self.end_node`, and use their `xGlobal` and `yGlobal` attributes.

```
class Elements:

    def __init__(self,number,length,start_node,end_node):
        self.number = number
        self.start_node = start_node
        self.end_node = end_node
        self.calc_length()

    def calc_length(self):
        self.length = mt.sqrt((self.start_node.xGlobal-self.end_node.xGlobal)**2 + (self.start_node.yGlobal-self.end_node.yGlobal)**2 )
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Just a short follow-up question: is it an efficient way to store the instances of the Node class in a numpy array, or is there a better method?

Comment: I don't see any reason to use numpy here. Just use a list.

Comment: Makes sense. I am new to python and a little confused about how arrays function here. I will improve the code and use a list instead. Thanks again for your help and time!